# Post to Facebook via API but Limit Access to FB App Users

Tags: facebook, social-networking

I've got a Facebook app that allows app "requests" to be sent to other Facebook friends.  What I would like to be able to do is then allow users to create status updates/posts that will only be visible to the FB App users who they have sent requests to previously.

I'm trying to do all of this via the FB Javascript API.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can but you'll have to manage the privacy limitation 'manually' by storing all invites in your own database.  The `apprequests` JS SDK call has a callback that contains a request_id and, more relevant to you - the facebook ids of the user who sent the invite and the user that was invited.  You'll have to save that information and then use it when posting.

Here is a link to the [facebook documentation on apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)... All the information you need about the callback and using the apprequests feature is located there...